# After latest update vscode does not even start

Tags: visual-studio-code

in my company laptop they did a central update on the vscode version and from one day to the other my code does not even start. (by company laptop means I don't really have admin access and can only try a few things to debug this)

I wanted to know how can I debug this because maybe is some additional plugin or something I might have that might be causing this problem.
It seems is not affecting other users so they don't really know what much can be.

anyway this is the stacktrace when I launch it, either from terminal or from the launcher.

```
Z:\>code
Error: Cannot find module 'iconv-lite'
Require stack:
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-amd.js
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:844:17)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:737:27)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:769:28)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at t.load (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:16:119)
    at e.load (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:13:586)
    at i (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:29:189)
    at Object.errorback (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:29:313)
    at e.triggerErrorback (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:13:955)
    at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:13:659
    at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:16:494)
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:239:13) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\resources\\app\\out\\bootstrap-amd.js',
    'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\resources\\app\\out\\cli.js'
  ],
  phase: 'loading',
  moduleId: 'iconv-lite',
  neededBy: [ 'vs/base/node/encoding' ]
}
Error: Cannot find module 'vscode-minimist'
Require stack:
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\bootstrap-amd.js
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:844:17)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:737:27)
    at Function.Module._load (electron/js2c/asar.js:769:28)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at t.load (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:16:119)
    at e.load (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:13:586)
    at i (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:29:189)
    at Object.errorback (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:29:313)
    at e.triggerErrorback (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:13:955)
    at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:13:659
    at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\loader.js:16:494)
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:239:13) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\resources\\app\\out\\bootstrap-amd.js',
    'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\resources\\app\\out\\cli.js'
  ],
  phase: 'loading',
  moduleId: 'vscode-minimist',
  neededBy: [ 'vs/platform/environment/node/argv' ]
}
```

Any idea what I might try? it's probably some configuration issue on my side.
I believe this to be the version of the latest update:
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49

I'm now trying to run a portable version of vscode without plugins to try and figure out what the problem is, if interesting this are the extensions I've found in my user profile folder:

```
ms-azuretools.vscode-docker-1.1.0
ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin-1.2.3
naco-siren.gradle-language-0.2.3
richardwillis.vscode-gradle-2.4.14
shd101wyy.markdown-preview-enhanced-0.5.13
tht13.html-preview-vscode-0.2.5
zxh404.vscode-proto3-0.4.2
abusaidm.html-snippets-0.2.1
angular.ng-template-0.1001.0
dbaeumer.jshint-0.10.21
dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-2.1.1
eamodio.gitlens-10.2.2
ecmel.vscode-html-css-0.2.3
esbenp.prettier-vscode-5.5.0
hookyqr.beautify-1.5.0
marlon407.code-groovy-0.1.2
```